# How do I print a non-null-terminated string using printf?

Tags: c, string, printf

How can I print a non-null-terminated string using printf, assuming that I know the length of the string at runtime?

Comment: If it's not null terminated, then by definition it's not a string.

Comment: it's only not a _c string_, as it would be a valid string in other languages.. and though a "non-null-terminated array of char" would be more accurate, I'm pretty sure it was universally understood.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using printf with a non-null terminated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767284/using-printf-with-a-non-null-terminated-string)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
printf("%.*s", length, string);
```

Use together with other args:

```
printf("integer=%d, string=%.*s, number=%f", integer, length, string, number);
//                         ^^^^                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

In C you could specify the maximum length to output with the `%.123s` format. This means the output length is at most 123 chars. The `123` could be replaced by `*`, so that the length will be taken from the argument of printf instead of hard-coded.

Note that this assumes the `string` does not contain any interior null bytes  (\0), as `%.123s` only constrains the *maximum* length not the *exact* length, and strings are still treated as null-terminated.

If you want to print a non-null-terminated string with interior null, you cannot use a single printf. Use `fwrite` instead:

```
fwrite(string, 1, length, stdout);
```

See [@M.S.Dousti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25111267/224671) for detailed explanation.

Comment: note: `length` must have type `int` here, after default argument promotions. If your `length` variable is something bigger (e.g. `size_t`) you should cast it to `(int)` else your code will break on a platform where `size_t` is wider than `int`.

Answer (score 24):

The answer provided by @KennyTM is great, but with a subtlety.

In general, if the string is non-null "terminated", but has a null character in the middle, `printf("%.*s", length, string);` does not work as expected. This is because the `%.*s` format string asks `printf` to print a **maximum** of `length` characters, not **exactly** `length` characters.

I'd rather use the more general solution pointed out by @William Pursell in a comment under the OP:

```
fwrite(string, sizeof(char), length, stdout);
```

Here's a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t length = 5;

    char string[length];
    string[0] = 'A';
    string[1] = 'B';
    string[2] = 0;        // null character in the middle
    string[3] = 'C';
    string[4] = 'D';

    printf("With printf: %.*s\n", length, string);
    printf("With fwrite: ");
    fwrite(string, sizeof(char), length, stdout);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
With printf: AB
With fwrite: AB CD
```

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition. Also, `NULL` is specifically a null *pointer* constant.

Comment: @KeithThompson, `sizeof (char)` is more semantic. Also, `'\0'` is more semantic than `0`. But who cares ;-)

Comment: My output for this is `With fwrite: AB` - it seems to be stopping at the null terminator. Compiled with gcc 4.8.5

Comment: @MatthewMoisen: See [Godbolt output](https://godbolt.org/z/CA-adM) for your compiler.