# libarchive reads too many chars when extracting a file

Tags: c, malloc, tar

I've written a C program to extract files from a tar archive using libarchive.

I'd like to extract a file from this archive and print it to standard output.  **But I get extra characters**.  It's garbage, but it's from another file (possibly adjacent to it in the archive.)  I expect output to end at `</html>`.

Here is the code that reads [this tar file](http://dev.dailyraisin.com/0000.tar):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "archive.h"
#include "archive_entry.h"


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    struct archive *a;
    struct archive_entry *entry;
    int r;
    int64_t entry_size;
    a = archive_read_new();
    archive_read_support_compression_none(a);
    archive_read_support_format_tar(a);
    r = archive_read_open_filename(a, "0000.tar", 1024);
    if (r != ARCHIVE_OK)
    {
        printf("archive not found");
    }
    else 
    {
        while (archive_read_next_header(a, &entry) == ARCHIVE_OK) 
        {
            const char *currentFile = archive_entry_pathname(entry);
            char *fileContents;
            entry_size = archive_entry_size(entry); //get the size of the file
            fileContents = malloc(entry_size); //alloc enough for string - from my testing I see that this is how many bytes tar and ls report from command line
            archive_read_data(a, fileContents, entry_size); //read data into fileContents string for the HTML file size
            if(strcmp(currentFile, "vendar-definition.html") == 0)
            {
                printf("file name = %s, size = %lld\n", currentFile, entry_size);
                printf("%s\n\n", fileContents); //this output over-reads chars from another file in this tar file
            }           
            free(fileContents); //free the C string because I malloc'd
        }
    }
    printf("exit");
    return 0;
}
```

[libarchive 2.8.3](http://libarchive.googlecode.com/files/libarchive-2.8.3.tar.gz) compiled on mac os X 10.6.3. gcc 4.2 x86_64

`ls -l vendar-definition.html` gives me `1921` for the file size.  And so shows `tar tfv 0000.tar | grep vendar-definition.html`.  So reports the C output that states the file size.  To me this seems correct.

Two possibilities I can see for why my output is not as expected:

1. I've made a beginner's mistake or
2. multibyte characters in the archive files has something to do with it.

Comment: wouldn't be better if fileContents and currentFile were declared outside while's block?

Comment: Also, my gcc complains when trying to use char* instead of void* for fileContents. Doing so, a simple printf( "%s", fileContents ) solved. Please, check if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be *very* wrong but that doesn't look like a null-terminated string (I don't think `archive_read_data` takes care of that). Append a NULL character or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137779/how-do-i-print-a-non-null-terminated-string-using-printf) and tell us how it goes.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't.  Perfect, that link set me straight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're not *reading* too many chars, but only *printing* too many.

You're outputting the file contents using the `%s` specifier to `printf`, which expects the input to be a null-terminated string. The contents of a file in the archive may not be null-terminated, and may contain arbitrary nulls in the middle.

Try outputting like this instead:

```
fwrite(fileContents, sizeof(char), entry_size, stdout);
```