# How does %s work in c without `&` in scanf?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I had some confusion about `%s` in c. I am new to programming and I am learning c as my fist P.L.

How does `%s` works in c. I had found that **you don't need to use `&` in scanf while using `%s`. Why is this so?** **Why `%s` gives segmentation fault when I use**

```
char *a="how are you";
printf("%s",*a);
```

I had read this link:- [Using %s in C correctly - very basic level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980878/using-s-in-c-correctly-very-basic-level#9981203)  but I want the answers of questions that are in bold.

Comment: Time for you to dust off your copy of K & R and read it.

Comment: The question you link to has the answer you seek.

Comment: When you use `scanf` you need to provide the __pointer__ to the variable. That's why you use the `&` sign, `&x` meaning "address of x". Now when you scanf a _string_ like in `char string[100]; ... scanf("%s", s);`, `s` __is__ already the pointer to the string.

Comment: Try to understand why the following works instead, and everything will be clearer: `printf("%s",&(*a));`

Comment: It works because C is internally inconsistent in the way it handles arrays vs. other types.  Dennis R. was drunk when defining how to pass arrays as arguments.

Comment: Learn about pointers. Any book will help you with. SO is not a learning site

Comment: Take the compiler's warning serious. Read them and learn to understand them.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand the difference between a pointer and a `char` variable.

In `scanf()` you usually pass an array to match a `%s` specifier, then a pointer to the first element of the array is used in it's place. For other specifiers like `%d` you need to pass the address of the target variable to allow `scanf()` to store the result in it.

In contrast, `printf()` does not store results anywhere, so it simply needs the value of the variable except for the `"%s"` specifier where it needs the address to the first element of an array of non `'\0'` `char` values terminated by a `'\0'`.

In your example, you are passing a `char` variable, `printf()` will take it as an address and attempt to dereference it which will cause a Segmentation Fault, because it expects the variable to be the address of an array filled with `char`s and terminated with a `'
0'`.

---

<sub>**Note**: `printf("%s", *a);` is equivalent to `printf("%s", a[0]);` so you can see clearly that the variable passed for `"%s"` is of type `char` and `printf()` will do something like `*(char *) 'h'` using `(char *) 'h'` as a valid pointer, but is most likely NOT.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Statement "you dont need to use & in scanf while using %s" might be misleading.
A `scanf` format specifier that is about reading in and storing a value *always* requires a pointer to an object of the respective type. This is usually achieved by unary `&`-operator, which returns the address of an object. Yet some types like arrays automatically decay to a pointer to the first element of the array, such that the following code actually passes a pointer:

```
char text[100] = "";
scanf("%s", text);  // array automatically decays to a pointer to the first element.
scanf("%s", &text[0]);  // explicitly take the address of the first element
```

If you do not have an array but a pointer to char, the code changes as follows:

```
char *text2 = malloc(100);
scanf("%s", text2);  // text2 is a pointer, not an array
```

Again, you do not need an `&`, because you already pass the pointer value.

So statement "you dont need to use & in scanf while using %s" is true as `%s` always requires a pointer to a sequence of characters, and either you pass an array which automatically decays to a pointer or you pass a pointer directly.

Your code is wrong from two perspectives:

```
char *a="how are you";
printf("%s",*a);
```

First, `*a` is not a pointer but a single character value (`'h'` in your case), which - when converted to a pointer value - will be something like memory address `0x0000001A`. Accessing this yields undefined behaviour / seg fault.

Second, it's a `printf`, not a `scanf`. If you want a printf, write:

```
char *a="how are you";
printf("%s",a);
```

If you want a scanf, write:

```
char a[100];;
scanf("%s",a);
```

Comment: What happens when I use `printf("%s, *test);` where `char *a="how are you";`.I am keep getting segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf()` function expects a pointer the first element of a character array as an argument with the `%s` directive. Since an array identifier decays to a pointer to the first element of the array (in most expressions, including function calls), simply using the array name without the `&` address operator provides the correct pointer. In fact, using the `&` operator here is wrong.

Given the code:

```
char array[100];
int ret_val = scanf("%99s", array);
```

Here the identifier `array` decays to a pointer to the first element of `array[]`, which is what `scanf()` expects. If instead, this:

```
int ret_val = scanf("%99s", &array);
```

This is incorrect, since `&array` is a pointer to the array `array[]`. The difference is, `array` decays to a pointer to one byte, while `&array` is a pointer to 100 bytes (in this case). This difference matters, for example, when pointer arithmetic is involved.

In your second example:

```
char *a = "how are you";
printf("%s", *a);
```

Here, `a` is already a pointer to the first element of an array (since `a` is a pointer to `char` and `"how are you"` is a string literal, represented in memory as a null terminated array of `char`, which decays to a pointer to the first element of this array in the expression). By using `*a` instead of `a`, the value `'h'` is given as an argument to `printf()` instead of the expected pointer, leading to undefined behavior.

Also, note that in my first example, the return value of `scanf()` is stored in the `int` variable `ret_val`. `scanf()` returns the number of successful assignments made, and this value should be checked in robust code. Further, note that a maximum width should always be specified when using `%s` with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflow. Here, `%99s` is used, leaving space for the null terminator (`\0`) at the end of the array.