# Base64 decoding - bit shift results in unexpected end of char array in C

Tags: c, base64, bit-shift

I already used a lot of different functions to decode Base64 encoded char array in C. Right now, I am using this function to decode Base64 char array.

```
    unsigned int b64_decode(const unsigned char* in, unsigned int in_len, unsigned char* out) {

    unsigned int i=0, j=0, k=0, s[4];

    for (i=0;i<in_len;i++) {
        s[j++]=b64_int(*(in+i));
        if (j==4) {
            out[k+0] = ((s[0]&255)<<2)+((s[1]&0x30)>>4);
            if (s[2]!=64) {
                out[k+1] = ((s[1]&0x0F)<<4)+((s[2]&0x3C)>>2);
                if ((s[3]!=64)) {
                    out[k+2] = ((s[2]&0x03)<<6)+(s[3]); k+=3;
                } else {
                    k+=2;
                }
            } else {
                k+=1;
            }
            j=0;
        }
    }

    return k;
}
```

The problem is, that for a Base64 string like this **QKSRjAEAAAAB3bW3rVpoJOA8bsb3eEuEEDiq**, I am getting a string with only five characters, even the decoded text should be much longer. I tried to debug the code and it is because the result of the bit shift for the sixth character is 0, which unexpectedly ends the string. Online Base64 decoders decoded the mentioned string without problems.

I then want to convert the decoded string to hex. I am doing that like this:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; ++i, j += 2) {
                sprintf(data_hex + j, "%02x", decoded_data[i] & 0xff);
            }
```

Example of expected input: **QKSRjAEAAAAB3bW3rVpoJOA8bsb3eEuEEDiq**

Example of expected output: **40a4918c0100000001ddb5b7ad5a6824e03c6ec6f7784b841038aa**

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Have you tried some of the decoders located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c)?

Comment: Yes, I tried the OpenSSL solution, but with the same result.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137779/how-do-i-print-a-non-null-terminated-string-using-printf

Comment: The result is @¤‘Ś with size 5

Comment: Are you trying to use printf?  That won't work.  Try `fwrite(string, 1, length, stdout);`

Comment: I tried, there are more characters, but not all of them. The problem is, I need to convert characters of a decoded string to hex. I just edited my post. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Well, it took awhile to figure out where you got this code from.  The key was realizing that `b64_int()` is not a standard library function.

So for posterity, the original source for your code is [here](https://initrd.net/stuff/tetra-kit/decoder/), in files [base64.h](https://initrd.net/stuff/tetra-kit/decoder/base64.h) and [base64.cc](https://initrd.net/stuff/tetra-kit/decoder/base64.cc).

Here is the program that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "base64.h"

int main(void) {

  unsigned char in[] = "QKSRjAEAAAAB3bW3rVpoJOA8bsb3eEuEEDiq\0";
  int inLength = strlen((char*)in);

  unsigned char out[1000]; 
  unsigned int outLength = b64_decode(in, inLength, out);
  
  // Prints the result in Hexadecimal format.
  for (int i = 0; i < outLength; i++)
    printf("%x", out[i]);

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The key is capturing the return value of the `b64_decode()`, which tells you how many bytes to expect in the result.  It's unclear if you did this or not, since you didn't provide a code example of your program calling the `b64_decode()` function.

[Working online demo](https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/InfiniteTurbulentLanservers#main.c)

Comment: Thank you for your response. That works fine, just for me the base64 encoded data does not have the '\0' terminator and I need to store the result in hexadecimal format for other purposes, and that is why I use sprintf in my example.