# Print a string of a given length

Tags: c, string

`printf("%s", ...)` assumes null-terminated string. If I have a string deliminated by a length, what is the best way to do?

Suppose `buf` is the start address of the string, `n` is the length of the string. I have the following code. Is it the best way to do so?

```
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i) {
    fputc(buf[i], stdout);
  }
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137779/how-do-i-print-a-non-null-terminated-string-using-printf

Comment: C lib defines a _string_ as ending with a _null chracter_.  "If I have a string deliminated by a length" is better described in C as a character array delimited by a length.  It is not a _string_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%.*s` format specifier to specify the length to print.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int length = 3;
    const char* str = "123456";
    printf("%.*s\n", length, str);
    return 0;
}
```

This example will print `123`.

Better way to print fixed-length data should be using `fwrite()`. `printf()` can do many thing, so it may be unnecessarily slow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int length = 3;
    const char* str = "123456";
    fwrite(str, sizeof(*str), length, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%.*s\n", length, str);` will not print to the length is a null character is encountered first.  `printf("%.*s\n", 7, "abc\0xyz");` only prints `"abc"`.  `fwrite()` will print all 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think using *fwrite* is also an overkill here a you are anyway printing a string (which is a set of char).
Instead you could just use *putchar()*, it writes to *stdio* by default.

```
while(i<n)
 putchar(buf[i++]);
```